# Powershell Script to get multiple types of file extensions down a specified path and rename the file names after

Tags: powershell

```
Get-Childitem -Path C:\temp\* -Include *.docx , *.txt 

Rename-Item -Newname ($_.Name -replace 'CASENUMBER', 'case1')
```

Kind of a PowerShell noob so any help on how to get this to work. Trying to go down a specified Path and rename only certain documents with those specified extensions.

Not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 3):

Described thoroughly in the official docs: [Rename multiple files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-5.1#example-4-rename-multiple-files). `Rename-Item` accepts `PSPath` as pipeline input for parameter `LiteralPath`:

```
Get-Childitem -Path C:\temp\* -Include *.docx , *.txt |
    Rename-Item -Newname {$_.Name -replace 'CASENUMBER', 'case1'} -WhatIf
```

Please note the `-WhatIf` parameter. Shows what would happen if the cmdlet runs. The cmdlet is not run. **Helpful while debugging**.